# Проверка полей на заполненность и соответствие формату на лету и при клике на submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте!

Пишу проверку полей на заполненность и соответствие формату. Скажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить эту же поверку на пустоту поля и при клике на submit? Сейчас у меня проверяет только при потере фокуса `change` и при каждом набранном символе `keyup`, хотелось бы и при клике на кнопку Войти. И заодно проверьте, все ли я правильно пишу, так как я только изучаю jQuery.

```js
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
$(".full-width").on("change keyup", function(){                 
    if( !$.trim($(this).val()) ){     
        $(this).addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Это поле обязательно для заполнения');                             }else{
        $(this).removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
    }
    if( $.trim($('#signin-password').val()) != ''){    
        if( $('#signin-password').val().length <= 2 ){
            $('#signin-password').addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Пожалуйста, введите 2 или более символов.');
        }else{
            $('#signin-password').removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
        }
    }
    if($('#signin-email').val() != ''){    
        if($('#signin-email').val().search(pattern) == -1){
            $('#signin-email').addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Поле email не соответствует формату');
        }else{
            $('#signin-email').removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
input.has-error {
  border: 1px solid #d76666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
  <input class="full-width" id="signin-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
  <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
</p>
<p>
  <label for="signin-password">Password</label>
  <input class="full-width" id="signin-password" type="text"  placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
  <span class="cd-error-message"></span>      
</p>
<p>
  <input class="full-width log-in" type="submit" name="log_in" value="Войти">
</p>
```

Comment: можете добавить костыль вроде `$('form').submit(function() { $('.full-width').trigger('change') });`

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko Так скорее всего не будет работать проверка на пустоту при клике на submit, скорее будет работать только в случае прохождения по полям с помощью `each`. Но и с помощью `trigger` у меня не получается сейчас. Покажите, пожалуйста, на примере моего кода. Можете сразу в ответ вставить мой код и поправить его:) Буду очень благодарен Вам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите функции для валидации значений `#signin-email` и `#signin-password`

```
// Валидация почты
function validateEmail (email) {
  if (email.length === 0) {
    return { error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения' };
  }
  var pattern = /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  if (email.search(pattern) === -1) {
    return { error: 'Поле email не соответствует формату' };
  }
  return { valid: true };
}

// Валидация пароля
function validatePassword (password) {
  if (password.length === 0) {
    return { error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения' };
  }
  if (password.length < 2) {
    return { error: 'Пожалуйста, введите 2 или более символов.' };
  }
  return { valid: true };
}
```

Далее функцию для работы с представлением

```
// $input - jQuery объект поля ввода input
// validate - функция валидации
function validateInput ($input, validate) {
  var result = validate($input.val());
  if (result.error) {
    $input.addClass('has-error')
          .next('span')
          .addClass('is-visible')
          .text(result.error);                          
  } else {
    $input.removeClass("has-error")
          .next('span')
          .removeClass('is-visible')
          .text('');
  }
  return result.valid;
}
```

И наконец обработчики событий

```
var $signinEmail = $('#signin-email').on('change keyup', function () {
  validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail);
});

var $signinPassword = $('#signin-password').on('change keyup', function () {
  validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword);
});

$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  var valid = validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail)
            & validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword);
  if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault(); // если одно из полей не валидно, не отправляем форму
  }
});
```

```js
// Валидация почты
function validateEmail(email) {
  if (email.length === 0) {
    return {
      error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения'
    };
  }
  var pattern = /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  if (email.search(pattern) === -1) {
    return {
      error: 'Поле email не соответствует формату'
    };
  }
  return {
    valid: true
  };
}

// Валидация пароля
function validatePassword(password) {
  if (password.length === 0) {
    return {
      error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения'
    };
  }
  if (password.length < 2) {
    return {
      error: 'Пожалуйста, введите 2 или более символов.'
    };
  }
  return {
    valid: true
  };
}

function validateInput($input, validate) {
  var result = validate($input.val());
  if (result.error) {
    $input.addClass('has-error')
      .next('span')
      .addClass('is-visible')
      .text(result.error);
  } else {
    $input.removeClass("has-error")
      .next('span')
      .removeClass('is-visible')
      .text('');
  }
  return result.valid;
}

var $signinEmail = $('#signin-email').on('change keyup', function() {
  validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail);
});

var $signinPassword = $('#signin-password').on('change keyup', function() {
  validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword);
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var valid = validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail) &
    validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword);
  if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault(); // если одно из полей не валидно, не отправляем форму
  }
});
```

```css
input.has-error {
  border: 1px solid #d76666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-password">Password</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-password" type="text" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="full-width log-in" type="submit" name="log_in" value="Войти">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!:) Скажите, пожалуйста, а если полей будут более 2, например, 6 полей у меня при регистрации и 4 поля являются просто обязательными без какой-либо дополнительной валидации, т.е. придётся также для каждого поля писать отдельную функцию? Или это можно сделать как-то универсально, добавив какой-то кусочек кода, вот только какой?:)  То что Вы написали у меня будет использоваться для входа, эти же самые функции я буду использовать и для регистрации, не хватает только 4 полей, которые просто обязательные.

Comment: Можно написать еще одну функцию для проверки обязательности наподобие `validateEmail` или `validatePassword` и использовать ее для других 4-х полей. Всё же рекомендую также посмотреть на сторонние библиотеки для валидации, например, [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Я добавил код ответом, но помечать его не буду, это для Вас показать.Сейчас при не заполненном поле имя (при `change` и `keyup`) подсветится и поле логин. Подскажите, что не так. А при клике на кнопку отправить все поля помечаются, как обязательные, т.е. то что и нужно.

Comment: Два `input` имеют одинаковый класс `.requed`, с ними надо работать по отдельности. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/87vLscx7/) решения текущей задачи. Всё же рекомендую не изобретать велосипед и использовать готовую библиотеку для валидации.

Comment: Спасибо, отлично! Возник еще такой вопрос, может Вы знаете. Как делают так, чтобы при первом вводе не срабатывал keyup, а только `change`, а после ошибок уже работал и `keyup`? Допустим не очень думаю приятно человеку, когда он начал только вводить свой емайл, а ему уже по каждой букве выдает сообщение, что емайл не соответствует формату, куда приятнее выдать на первый раз после потери фокуса (`change`) ошибку, если что-то не так, а далее уже можно и `keyup`, чтобы отслеживать результат по буковке. Не раз такое встречал на сайтах.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Решил сделать более универсальнее Ваш код. Теперь нет необходимости для каждого поля писать `$('здесь id или класс').on('change keyup'...` , достаточно задать полю класс `requed` и нужное значение `data-var`, думаю так удобнее, а при необходимости можно еще дописать какие-то функции в `validators`. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, всё ли я правильно сделал, а так всё работает вроде как хорошо. Очень понравился Ваш вариант, Вы гений:) [Ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/87vLscx7/25/)

Answer (score 2):

Оборачиваем поля тегом `<form>`, обрабатываем её событие сабмита (обратите внимание, что для данного примера я добавил `return false`, чтобы форма в конечном счете не отправлялась) и внутри вызываем `$(".full-width").trigger('change')`.

```js
var pattern = /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
$(".full-width").on("change keyup", function() {
  console.log('field checked');
  
  if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
    $(this).addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Это поле обязательно для заполнения');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
  }
  if ($.trim($('#signin-password').val()) != '') {
    if ($('#signin-password').val().length <= 2) {
      $('#signin-password').addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Пожалуйста, введите 2 или более символов.');
    } else {
      $('#signin-password').removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
    }
  }
  if ($('#signin-email').val() != '') {
    if ($('#signin-email').val().search(pattern) == -1) {
      $('#signin-email').addClass('has-error').next('span').addClass('is-visible').text('Поле email не соответствует формату');
    } else {
      $('#signin-email').removeClass("has-error").next('span').removeClass('is-visible').text('');
    }
  }
});

$("#test-form").submit(function() {
  console.log('submit event triggered');
  $(".full-width").trigger('change');

  return false;
});
```

```css
input.has-error {
  border: 1px solid #d76666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test-form">
  <p>
    <label for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-password">Password</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-password" type="text" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="full-width log-in" type="submit" name="log_in" value="Войти">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Как будет время, протестирую у себя:)

Comment: Попробовал устанавливать `var error = 0; // флаг заполнения обязательных полей` в `$(".full-width").on("change keyup", function() {..}`, затем менять при ошибках на значение error = 1, но значение `error` до `$("#test-form").submit(function()` при клике не доходит почему-то:( Как это можно исправить подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: отслеживайте изменения вашей переменной в дебаггере, так вы увидите как и где она меняется или не меняется.
а вообще, если вы не просто тренируетесь, а делаете валидацию для живого проекта, то пользуйтесь HTML5 validation API и не парьтесь лишний раз.

Comment: Отслеживал. В итоге при первом клике на кнопку отправить приходит значение error = 0, а после того, как еще раз кликнешь и на последующие клики приходит error = 1. Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/m8ek20ur/), посмотрите, пожалуйста. Хочу разобраться.

Comment: Ну да, все правильно работает — вы в начале задали error = 0, а потом при одной из ошибок error = 1, и все, назад пути нет, к нулю вы error уже нигде не приводите при отсутствии ошибок.

Comment: А Вы откройте консоль и попробуйте сами, я приводил обратно к нулю, ситуация еще хуже. Пришлось вынести переменную error из функции, так как внутри функции change keyup она не доходит до submit. Продемонстрируйте правильное решение:)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hy0fwyf9/1/ вот так, например. Пишем в объект ошибки как error.ключ = false и правим на true если все ок, потом проверяем во время сабмита есть ли значения false в объекте и выводим в консоль соответствующие сообщения.

Comment: заполните поле Password, а поле E-mail не заполняйте и нажмите ВОЙТИ. В результате в консоли покажет - ошибок нет, при том что поле E-mail осталось не заполненным:)

Comment: блин, не ту версию фиддла кинул - https://jsfiddle.net/hy0fwyf9/

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Вашу помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Валидация почты
function validateEmail(email) {
  if (email.length === 0) {
    return {
      error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения'
    };
  }
  var pattern = /^[a-z0-9_.-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{1,6}\.)?[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
  if (email.search(pattern) === -1) {
    return {
      error: 'Поле email не соответствует формату'
    };
  }
  return {
    valid: true
  };
}

// Валидация пароля
function validatePassword(password) {
  if (password.length === 0) {
    return {
      error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения'
    };
  }
  if (password.length < 2) {
    return {
      error: 'Пожалуйста, введите 2 или более символов.'
    };
  }
  return {
    valid: true
  };
}
function validateRequed(requed) {
  if (requed.length === 0) {
    return {
      error: 'Это поле обязательно для заполнения'
    };
  }
  return {
    valid: true
  };
}
function validateInput($input, validate) {
  var result = validate($input.val());
  if (result.error) {
    $input.addClass('has-error')
      .next('span')
      .addClass('is-visible')
      .text(result.error);
  } else {
    $input.removeClass("has-error")
      .next('span')
      .removeClass('is-visible')
      .text('');
  }
  return result.valid;
}

var $signinEmail = $('#signin-email').on('change keyup', function() {
  validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail);
});

var $signinPassword = $('#signin-password').on('change keyup', function() {
  validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword);
});

var $signinRequed = $('.requed').on('change keyup', function() {
  validateInput($signinRequed, validateRequed);
});

$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  var valid = validateInput($signinEmail, validateEmail) &
    validateInput($signinPassword, validatePassword) & validateInput($signinRequed, validateRequed);
  if (!valid) {
    e.preventDefault(); // если одно из полей не валидно, не отправляем форму
  }
});
```

```css
input.has-error {
  border: 1px solid #d76666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-login">Логин</label>
    <input class="full-width requed" id="signin-login" type="text" placeholder="Логин" name="login">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-name">Имя</label>
    <input class="full-width requed" id="signin-name" type="text" placeholder="Имя" name="name">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="signin-password">Password</label>
    <input class="full-width" id="signin-password" type="text" placeholder="Пароль" name="password">
    <span class="cd-error-message"></span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="full-width log-in" type="submit" name="log_in" value="Войти">
  </p>
</form>
```